# what is rootState in vuejs, vuex context

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I tried to understand what a `rootState` is with vuejs, vuex ... but couldn't find clear explanation (google, or other forums) with these key words:

- what is "root state" vuejs
- understand "root state" vuejs
- etc

Can anyone explain what is it, and how we take advantage of its usage ?

Comment: Well i readed the docs and i think if you have modules in your store they have their own `state` and maybe you want to access the state outside of the modules so you gonna use `rootState`

Comment: Thank you, but how & why is this an advantage ? Could you share the doc pls ?

Comment: [Accessing global assets in namespaced modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#accessing-global-assets-in-namespaced-modules).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To better structure your code, you can split the vuex store in different modules. See the [reference](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html) on that.

Here an example of my store in a project I'm currently working on:

[image: store]

In my project I need several data from an API so I decided to split my store after this API response to bundle all functionalities that belongs together in one module. The `index.js` is used to put all the modules togehter and export the store:

```
...
import categories from './modules/categories'
import transportation from './modules/transportation'
import insurances from './modules/insurances'
import booking from './modules/booking'

Vue.use(Vuex)


export default new Vuex.Store({

    modules: {
        categories,
        transportation,
        insurances,
        booking
    },

    state: {
        // here I have general stuff that doesn't need to be split in modules
    },

    mutations: {
        // general stuff
    },

    actions: {
        // general stuff
    },

    strict: true
})
```

The `rootState` gets important if I need to access the general stuff in the `index.js` or if I want to access data from a module from inside another module.

E.g.:

To put a booking I need to know which categorie is selected from the current user of my app. To achive this I simply can use the `rootState` prop in the action:

```
/modules/categories.js

export default {
    namespaced: true,

    state: {
        categories: [ // data I need acces to ]
    }


/modules/booking.js

actions: {
    async PUT_BOOKING({ state, commit, dispatch, rootState }) {
          // access categories 
          const categories = rootState.categories.categories
          // rootState -> access root 
          // categories -> namespaced module in store
          // categories -> state categorie in namespaced module
    }
}
```

You can for example also pass `rootGetters` to an action. In my example I have a `getter` in my categories module that return the index of the currently selected categorie from the categorie array (=`state` prop).

```
async PUT_BOOKING({ state, commit, dispatch, rootState, rootGetters }) {
      // access categories 
      const categories = rootState.categories.categories

      // acces index of selected categorie
      const index = rootGetters['categories/selCategorie']
}
```

Hopefully my example was understandable and I could help you a little.

Comment: Very clear answer and usecase example. Thank alot.